# Is it best practice to include current month or only previous completed months in monthly average equation?

Tags: average, calculation

I am trying to calculate a rolling "monthly average" equation for personal expenses and wondering if I should include the current month before it is over or if I should only include previous, fully completed months?

For instance, in mid-September, should I include **January - August** OR **January - September** and so on?

Comment: Depends on the purpose.

Comment: I think @PM77-1 is right. But sounds like adding the current month to the average will defect your calculations reliability (Because half month is not in consistence with the previous's months expenses).

Comment: Ok thank you. It is for budget reasons. Important numbers I want to know are: total average monthly expense, and average monthly expense for cable or gas. 
cc @PM77-1